# Can't see Windows Boot Manager in my BIOS setup

Tags: boot, bios, pxe

I have a Razer Blade 15. When I boot my device, a message is flashed which says,

> > Checking Media Presence.....
> > No Media Present.....

but this message is only flashed for a second and then my laptop boots up normally. I went to the Boot menu of my BIOS and found that I only have PXE boot options. Image attached below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7n3M.jpg)

I do not find Windows Boot Manager as a Boot option, nor can I find options to select my SSD, HDD or a USB in the boot priority order. How can I resolve it? I have seriously no knowledge about BIOS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you reset the BIOS to default values (and save / restart)  .    Does this work?

Comment: Hi John! I have tried resetting the bios to default values. Nothing changes.